# Need advice on understanding Rand() and XOR in C++

Tags: c++, random, xor

Here is the code I am referring to:

```
int main ()
{
    // Random training sets for XOR -- two inputs and one output

    cout << "topology: 2 4 1" << endl;
    for (int i = 2000; i >= 0; --i) {
        int n1 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
        int n2 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
        {
            int t = n1 ^ n2; // should be 0 or 1
            cout << "in: " << n1 << ".0 " << n2 <<  ".0 " << endl;
            cout << "out: " << t << ".0" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems these two lines are the same save for `n1` and `n2`:

```
int n1 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
int n2 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
```

But when I cout `(int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX))` the answer always seems to come out as 1.

So how could this line be true:

```
int t = n1 ^ n2; // should be 0 or 1
```

The output of the code shows it to be i/e:

```
in: 1.0 0.0 
out: 1.0
in: 0.0 1.0 
out: 1.0
in: 1.0 0.0 
out: 1.0
in: 0.0 1.0 
out: 1.0
in: 0.0 0.0
```

But `(1 ^ 1)` as in `t = n1 ^ n2` always cout's as 0. So how is the above output possible? Or am I just not cout-ing these lines enough (I did each one many times, like 10 each).

**Edit** 
What I don't understand is every time I both compile and run the line `cout << (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));` it outputs a 1 and `n1` and `n2` both equal `(int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));` so how could `t = n1 ^ n2` ever come out to  1? Yet there it is.

Comment: Are you calling `srand` to seed the random number generator?

Comment: Your output looks absolutely correct to me. Why do you doubt that it is possible?

Comment: It's not clear what it is you don't understand. Do you not understand why calling `rand` exactly once in a program returns the same value every time you run that program? Do you not understand what `^` does? Or what?

Comment: [Looks right to me](http://ideone.com/0cXaBd) (at least for what you're doing).

Comment: @David Schwartz pls see latest edits....Thanks for your reply btw

Comment: @Anton Poznyakovskiy pls see latest edits

Comment: Read my answer again I edited it to explain why it's always 1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random number generator `rand()` will always give you 1 first time you run program.. if you don't want to make it always give 1 the first time then set the randon number generators seed to a different value because right now it always uses the same default seed. call the command `srand()` to change seed value, you could make it more random everytime by setting the random number generators seed to your computer clock that way it would look more random

using this code

```
#include <ctime>

srand((unsigned)time(0));
```

I see nothing wrong with it, I made it on 1 line maybe your eyes just playing tricks on you, http://ideone.com/WaMihm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // Random training sets for XOR -- two inputs and one output

    cout << "topology: 2 4 1" << endl;
    for (int i = 2000; i >= 0; --i) {
        int n1 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
        int n2 = (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX));
        int t = n1 ^ n2; // should be 0 or 1
        cout << "[A]in: " << n1 << " [B]in: " << n2 <<  " out: " << t << endl;
    }
}
```

.

```
Output:
topology: 2 4 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 1 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
[A]in: 1 [B]in: 0 out: 1
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 0 out: 0
[A]in: 0 [B]in: 1 out: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your edits that was the answer I was looking for ....I couldn't accept both of those great answers so I chose yours And upped David's....Thanks again for all of your guys help=)

Answer (score 0):

> Edit what I don't understand is every time I both compile and run the line cout << (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX)); it outputs a 1 and n1 and n2 both equal (int) (2.0 * rand() / double(RAND_MAX)); so how could t = n1 ^ n2 ever come out to 1 yet there it is

The *first* time you call it, it outputs a 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      int j = (2.0 * rand () / double (RAND_MAX));
      printf ("%d\n", j);
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
1
0
1
1
1
0
...
```

Since your implementation of `rand` may differ, so may your output.

Because the random number generator starts out in the same state each time you run the program, it produces the same first result each time. But calling `rand` changes the state, so the next call to `rand` from the same instance can produce different output.